# Convert Year+WeekOfYear+DayOfWeek to a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have date values identified by a year, the week number within that year and the weekday and want to convert those into simple dates.

I couldn't find a function or another simple way to combine those, so I came up with a workaround using `generate_series` to get all dates in a range and JOIN the extracted values of those with my data:

```
SELECT data.*, days.d result
FROM ( VALUES (2017, 33, 3) ) data(d_year, d_week, d_weekday)
JOIN (
  SELECT
    -- the potential castdate
    d::date d
    -- year-week-dayofweek combination for JOINing
    , EXTRACT('year' FROM d) d_year, EXTRACT('week' FROM d) d_week, EXTRACT('dow' FROM d) d_weekday
  FROM generate_series('2015-01-01', '2019-12-31', INTERVAL '1day') AS days(d)
) days
  USING(d_year, d_week, d_weekday)
```

Result is:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
| d_year | d_week | d_weekday |   result   |
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
|   2017 |     33 |         3 | 16.08.2017 |
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

While this works, this seems like overkill for such a simple task. Moreover, if one doesn't have a fixed range, this might not even work.

Is there an easier way to this?

Comment: What's the expected result for (2019,1,2)? Could be both 2019-12-31 and 2019-01-01.

Comment: @jarlh why would be 2019-12-31 ?

Comment: @jarlh
How could that be 2019-12-31? The week number would be either 52 or 53 (did not look it up), but not 1...

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, This year both December 30 and 31 are in week 1. (As well as January 1 to 6, but a different week 1.) 2019 has no week 53, and week 52's last day is Sunday December 29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3282233ebc264c23203b9e2b11430c53)

you can use the `to_date()` function, which takes an date string as argument, as well as a format pattern. So if the date string may be `'2017-33-3'`, you could take this pattern to clarify each date part:

```
'IYYY-IW-ID'
```

1. `'ID'`: The tricky part is: Does your week start with Sunday oder with Monday? This question influences the solution because it would shift the week numbers in an unexpected ways if you don't think about it. Thanks to your expected output, I saw you need `'ID'` (ISO week day, week starts mondays) instead of `'D'` (week day, week start sundays.)
2. `'IW'`: Because we are taking the ISO week day, we need the ISO week of year as well (instead of `'WW'`: week of year)
3. `'IYYY'`: Similar to (2)

More information about date patterns (especially the ISO thing): [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

```
SELECT to_date(d_year || '-' || d_week || '-' || d_weekday, 'IYYY-IW-ID')
```

---

If you used the standard week pattern: `'YYYY-WW-D'`, your result would be `2017-08-13` (see fiddle)

---

Of course, this works also without the `-` characters, but it might be less readable:

```
SELECT to_date(d_year || d_week || d_weekday, 'IYYYIWID')
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already marked this as solved, but I only upvoted...